# I don't know how to use the stack in mips (assembly)

Tags: stack, mips

I give the code that has a problem and the use of the stack may not work..

Can anyone tell me ho to fix this?

```
.data
.align 2
array:.space 100
.text
.globl main

main:
  li $t0,10


  addi $sp,$sp,-12     #stack
  sw $ra,0($sp)
  sw $s0,4($sp)
  sw $s1,8($sp)
  jal function
  addi $sp,$sp,12
  lw $ra,0($sp)    #hello stack
  lw $s0,4($sp)
  lw $s1,8($sp)
  li $v0,1
  add $a0,$t6,$0
  syscall
  li $v0,10
  syscall

function:
  move $s0,$a2
  move $s1,$a1     
   li $s0,10101    # s0,s1   dont change itsvalues NEVER 
   li $s1,20202
   li $t6,777
   move $v0,$t6
   jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about "delay slots" in MIPS processors?
The next instruction after any "branch" instructions is placed in "delay slot". It means that this instruction will be executed anyway even if the branch was performed. So in the next piece of code:

```
  jal function
  addi $sp,$sp,12
```

you need to place `nop` instruction after `jal` because `addi` is executed right away after call but not after the returning from `function`. It also resides to `jr` instruction.